# Combining two `numpy` arrays by using one as index for columns

Tags: numpy

If I have two `numpy arrays`

```
arr1
Out  [7]: array([1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0])
```

and

```
arr2
Out  [6]: 
array([[0.10420547, 0.8957946 ],
       [0.6609819 , 0.3390181 ],
       [0.16680466, 0.8331954 ],
       ...,
       [0.27138624, 0.7286138 ],
       [0.6883444 , 0.31165552],
       [0.70164204, 0.298358  ]], dtype=float32)
```

what is the quickest way to return a new array `arr3` in such a way that `arr1` indicates the column that I want from `arr2` for each row? I would like to return something like:

```
arr3
array([0.8957946, 0.6609819, 0.8331954, ... ])
```

I would do it by filling a new empty array and iterating but I can't think of a quicker way right now.

EDIT:

Ok, a way that I found is the following, but probably not optimal (?):

```
arr3 = np.array([arr2[i][arr1[i]] for i in range(len(arr2))])
```

returns

```
arr3
Out  [23]: 
array([0.8957946 , 0.6609819 , 0.8331954 , ..., 0.7286138 , 0.6883444 ,
       0.70164204], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: `arr2[np.arange(len(arr2)), arr1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
np.take_along_axis(arr2,arr1[:,None],1).squeeze()
```